# Shared objects/functions between multiple browserwindows in electron

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, electron, reusability

In my application I've got two browser-windows (main_win and info_win).
Now

- I want to access a variable which is hold in global.js.
- In **main**_win_controller.js I do a `global = require('../global.js');` and then write to the variable initial/once like this: `global.myVar = "from main_win";`
- In **info**_win_controller.js I do a `global = require('../global.js');` and then write to the variable initial/once like this: `global.myVar = "from info_win";`
- After doing so I read the variables continiousely via a interval for testing in both files. Both outputs are different so it seems like I've got two independent instances of my global.js

How can I get rid of this? I want to realise a central part of my application where I can define special reuseable functions (*in my example I want to use here the GPIO-Pins of my Raspberry Pi via the use of a special npm-module*)

Comment: How does the code of global.js look like ?

Comment: there is no concrete concept for this. Maybe just exportet functions like `export myGlobalFoo = () => {...}`.